# Dynamic 2D array crashes

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I am reading from a file (each line wolds 1 word) and putting each line into an array. It crashes when its about to close the file saying (*** glibc detected *** proj: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000002139240 ***).  Also everything but the 1st element was copied correctly (the 1st element was supposed to be "how are you" but was instead "0").  Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

```
int i = -1;
int numb;
int wsize; 
while (fgets(word,30,file)!=NULL)
{
    if (i==-1)
    {
         if(word[strlen(word)-1]=='\n')
         {
             word[strlen(word)-1] = 0;
         }
         numb = atoi(word);
         ptr = malloc(sizeof(char*)*numb);
    }
    else
    {
        if(word[strlen(word)-1]=='\n')
        {
             word[strlen(word)-1] = 0;
        }
        wsize = strlen(word);
        ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*)*wsize);
        strncpy(ptr[i],word,strlen(word));
        size++;
     }
     i++;
}
int j=0;
while(j<16)     //prints to see if they were copied corectly
{               //ptr[0] was the only one that did not copy corectly
    printf("%s\n",ptr[j]);       
    j++;
}
fclose(file);
printf("test\n"); //was never printed so I assume it crashes at fclose()
return 1;
```

Comment: before exiting the program, the code needs to free all those malloc'd areas.  Otherwise a series of memory leaks are created.  While the exiting of the program will (sadly) free all the allocated memory, it is far better to have code cleanup after itself, especially as the programs get larger, run for longer durations, and have more and more allocated memory to free

Answer (score 0):

The line `ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*)*wsize);` is wrong, for two reasons:

1. It should be `sizeof(char)`, not `sizeof(char*)` (or just omit this, since `sizeof(char)` is equal to 1 by definition)
2. If you want to store a string of length `wsize`, you need to allocate `wsize+1` bytes

**EDIT — More issues:**

3. What is the purpose of the line `size++;`? Did you mean `wsize++;`?
4. Where does the number 16 come from in `while(j<16)`? I suggest you try `while(j<i)` instead.
5. If `main()` returns a nonzero value, this signifies that an error occurred. Change this to `return 0;` unless you have a good reason for returning some other value.

**One more:**

6. I just noticed you're using `strncpy()`. This won't add a terminating `'\0'` byte to the end of the string because you've asked it to copy a string of length `wsize` using no more than `wsize` bytes. Change this line to `strcpy(ptr[i],word);` and it should work.

After you've done that, you need to remove all the potential buffer overflows from your code. (There are lots of them.)

Comment: Size is the total size of ptr and is a variable that is passed by reference into this function. Wsize is the size of the current word taken from the line.
When testing this I used 16 cause I know there are 16 words. Once this error is fixed this will be removed.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, but how do I tell where a potential buffer overflow is?

Comment: @npzap If you know there are 16 words, why are you even bothering to store the number of words at the top of your file? Obviously your program is liable to crash if `numb` iz zero because it will still attempt to read in words until it reaches the EOF. Less obviously, it will also crash if `numb` = `(INT_MAX + 1) / sizeof(char*)` due to an arithmetic overflow in the `malloc()` statement. If there are fewer strings in the file than the number declared at the top, then your `printf()` calls will dereference unallocated pointers and cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: I know there are 16 words during my own test, this has to be made for any number of strings.  There will always be the number or words that the number at the top declares.  However thanks for the input about malloc and numb, I realized I was using numb wrong and found the solution.